# Table row dropdown toogle and hide after anywhere click

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I am trying to trying to create a togglable action dropdown for each row in the table, not able to understand how to make if togglable or making it go away when the user clicks elsewhere in the screen.

Following is my code

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td><a data-id="1" href="#" class="dropdown"> Action Dropdown</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td><a data-id="2" href="#" class="dropdown"> Action Dropdown</a></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td><a data-id="3" href="#" class="dropdown"> Action Dropdown</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="/action1/id">View</a>
  <a href="/action2/id">Edit</a>
  <a href="/action3/id">Delete</a>
</div>



$('.dropdown).on('click', function(e) {
  var $rowDropdownMenu = $('.dropdown-content');
  var id = $(this).data('id');

  $rowDropdownMenu = $rowDropdownMenu.html().replace(/id/g, id);         

  $(this).append($rowDropdownMenu);

  // Need some here for toggle

});
```

Answer (score 0):

May be  [this resolves](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_dropdowns.asp) your problem

Comment: Thank you for the quick solution. I am not using bootstrap in the application. Just Jquery